# where is a web reference stored in a compiled class library project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

In one of my web solutions I have a separate C# class library that uses a Web Reference to an external web service.

I have compiled the project, but due to the size/complexity of the overall solution, I can only afford to transfer files that have been modified.

Recently I have updated the web reference but need to reflect the changes on a live server. Does anybody know what file(s) this reference is stored in?

First thoughts are that it would be stored in the compiled DLL or accompanying config file, but I just can't seem to spot it (using Telerik JustDecompile).

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks!